loop in RMarkdown produces identical diagrams instead of a separate diagram for each file
The following scenario: I am supposed to create reports in R, where R automatically pulls the corresponding file, creates graphics, creates a pdf file and then does the same with the next 50 files. I have the RMarkdown document that contains the code and an execution script that should start the loop.
It's a bit complicated and I'm not sure which file contains the error. I have a folder in which all files for all classes are located. R is supposed to create a bar chart which always shows the data of the respective classes.
Instead, R creates a pdf file for each class, but the diagrams are all identical. Something does not seem to fit in the loop.
This is what my execution script looks like:
# Path to the data
data_path <- "Datapath"

# Function for rendering PDFs
render_pdf <- function(csv_file_t1, csv_file_t2) {
  # Extract file name (without path and extension)
  class <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(csv_file_t1))
  
  # Remove the suffix “_work_t1” from the variable “class”
  class <- gsub("_work_t1$", "", class)
  
  # Debugging: Check whether class was defined correctly
  print(paste("Class:", class))  
  
  # Rendern des R Markdown Dokuments mit den Parametern
  rmarkdown::render(
    input = "Datapath/report.Rmd", # Path to the Rmd file
    output_file = paste0("Report_", class, ".pdf"),
    params = list(
      class = class,
      file_t1 = csv_file_t1,
      file_t2 = csv_file_t2
    ),
    envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
  )
}


# List of CSV files for t1
csv_files_t1 <- list.files(path = data_path, pattern = "*_work_t1.csv", full.names = TRUE)

# Loop for rendering all PDFs for t1 and t2
for (file_t1 in csv_files_t1) {
  # Find the corresponding t2 file
  file_t2 <- gsub("_t1.csv$", "_t2.csv", file_t1)
  
  if (file.exists(file_t2)) {
    print(paste("Process file:", file_t1, "und", file_t2))
    render_pdf(file_t1, file_t2)  # Here file_t1 and file_t2 are used
  } else {
    print(paste("No corresponding t2 file found for:", file_t1))
  }
}


# Import Data
Dataframe <- read.csv2("Dataframe.csv")


And this is the part in the RMarkdown script where R should create the bar charts for each class:
# Filter textscores
textscores <- subset(Dataframe, consent == 1) %>%
  select(school_class, ExCon, text_scores_T1, text_scores_T2)

# Convert text scores to long format
textscores_long <- textscores %>%
  rename("August 2023" = text_scores_T1,
         "February 2024" = text_scores_T2) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("August 2023", "February 2024"), names_to = "MP", values_to = "Textscores")

# Convert class to character for the text scores DataFrame
textscores_long$school_class <- as.character(textscores_long$schoolclass)

# List of classes
class_list <- unique(Dataframe$school_class)

# Loop over the classes
for (class in class_list) {

  # Create df1 for the current class
  df1 <- textscores_long %>%
    bind_rows(textscores_long %>% mutate(school_class = 'all')) %>%
    group_by(school_class, MP) %>%
    summarise(Mean = mean(Textscores, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    filter(school_class %in% c(class)) %>%  # Dynamic class filter
    mutate(grp = "school_class") %>%
    rename("name" = school_class)

  # Create df2 for ExCon (Experimental and Control group)
  df2 <- textscores_long %>%
    group_by(ExCon, MP) %>%
    summarise(Mean = mean(Textscores, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    mutate(grp = "ExCon") %>%
    rename("name" = ExCon)
  
    # Convert name to character for both DataFrames
  df1$name <- as.character(df1$name)
  df2$name <- as.character(df2$name)

  # Visualization for the current class
  text_plot <- rbind(df1, df2) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = MP, y = Mean, fill = name)) +
    geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "steelblue", "steelblue1"),
                      name = NULL,
                      labels = c("Your class", "Experimental group", "Control group")) +
    theme_classic()
}

text_plot

I'm sorry that I can't provide any data because the whole thing is a bit more extensive. But I hope that someone will find the error in the script.

Almost certainly a lazy evaluation problem.  In addition, looking at your code, you overwrite text_plot with each evaluation of your loop before printing the most recent version outside your loop.  I suggest converting your for loop to a call to a member of the apply family.  dplyr::group_walk would also provide a solution.

Do you mean the for loop in my RMarkdown skript or in my execution script?

I was looking at the markdown script as how you create your dataset is usually irrelevant.  But for safety, I'd say both.  [You did check your input data to make sure it looks as you expect, didn't you?]

Yeah, I checked it several times. I also have network data in the same RMarkdown script. This worked perfectly fine. It is just the bar chart that does not work as expected...

I am sorry to ask again but I feel quite stuck. Could you please explain how I would use group_walk instead of the for loop? I tried scrolling through the help-page in R but I don't think the example is similar to my case..
